# Scala Error : identifier expected but ')' found

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala facing ***"identifier expected but ')' found"*** in below code

```
if (cell != null && cell.getCellType != Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)
```

Comment: The error is likely in the block that follows the `if (condition)` .  What code is supposed to run if the condition is `true`?

Comment: Maybe `Cell` is an enum and you need to import it together with the type defined in its object: `import mypackage.{Cell, _}`. Can't guess without seeing code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if (cell != null && cell.getCellType != Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)

formatting was wrong..

Thanks @Tzach Zohar